# Cannot publish react native apps because permission on android manifest

Tags: android, react-native

I got this problem yesterday, i think it because the change of google play console rules for android permissions.

so, i think google detect there is a some permission in my android manifest

although i have already use "tools:node="remove"" in every permission i don't use. Google still won't let me to rollout in google play console.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>         <!-- for Device Name -->
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  <!-- for Phone Number -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

this pretty much inside of my androidManifest.xml

the permission not shown in release apps but i think google still check my androidManifest.xml.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution> I'm having the same issue but with ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens, because Google is restricting the ["Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups".](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Can you check that you have added the tools namespace to your manifest:

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
</manifest>
```

If you haven't `tools:node="remove"` wont have any effect.

Comment: i already used it. it's already not shown in release apps. but google still think my apps need permission for SMS and Call log permission because it's still available in manifest.